What is the difference between true and correct?
Is there a difference between true and correct? If so, what is it? Have any philosophers made a fine distinction between the notion of truth and the notion of correctness? I would also like to see some texts where philosophers talk about this topic.

This sounds like more a question for a dictionary. If not, how are you defining the two terms? Apparently not as dictionary.com does; it defines "correct" as "conforming to truth."

It's a bit tangential, but you could draw a line between this and the difference between "knowledge" and "justified, true belief". Gettier problems. E.g. in those thought experiments, you could have a true belief, but perhaps you could say that it is not correct in that you don't have a correct understanding of why the belief is true? But I agree; words are empty, there isn't a "proper" definition of truth or correctness aside from "what we agree are useful definitions of those concepts"

Truth is factual, correctness is normative, which makes it a broader notion. An action or attitude can be correct in this or that situation, but they cannot be 'true' (other than metaphorically). That a claim is true is a fact about its content, that it is correct means that it is proper to make, albeit usually because it is true, see Gibbard, Truth and correct belief.

Certainly there is a difference between "a true Scotsman" and "a correct Scotsman".

Conifold mentioned the idea of truth being factual and correct being normative. I think that is largely a good summary. Correct is relative to some standard whereas true is relative to the actual world. The two can line up if our standard of correctness is truth.
I think a place where truth and correctness are categorically different is with verbs as opposed to nouns:
(1) "John pitched a fastball correctly" vs
(2) "It is true that john pitched a fastball"
(1) unambiguous once we document the definition of a "correct fastball technique". (2) is vague because it's not clear what defines a "fastball" vs "correct fastball". There is some wiggle room. Clearly "correct fastballs" are a subset actions that would satisfy (2), but are there "poorly thrown fastballs", "mediocre fastballs"?
So I think its possible to have correctness and truth represent different things.

The problem with this answer is that there are multiple senses of "correct", and one of them is roughly equivalent to "true". E.g. "It's true/correct that 2+2 == 4"

I would argue that correctness is often a subset of truth. It is true but in many cases not correct that 2+2 equals a number, but both true and correct that 2+2=4.

@Barmar — see response by Cam.
I mention the same thing in this part of my post:  “”Clearly "correct fastballs" are a subset actions that would satisfy (2), but are there "poorly thrown fastballs", "mediocre fastballs"?
So I think it’s possible to have correctness and truth represent different things. “”
